# The relationship between conjugacy quandles and associated groups.

Tags: category-theory

Does the equation $As(Conj(G))=G$ hold?

Given a group $G$, we define a *conjugacy quandle* $Conj(G)=G$ with quandle operation $q*r=r^{-1}qr$. Given a quandle $Q$, we define an *associated group*, often called
an *enveloping group*, as:
$$
As(Q)=\langle e_q\,(q\in Q)\mid e_{q*r}=e_r^{-1}e_qe_r\,(q,r\in Q)\rangle.
$$
Then, both $As$ and $Conj$ are functors. The pair $(As,Conj)$ forms an adjunction pair. We have the natural transformation $\varepsilon:As\circ Conj\to Id$. This means that, for any group $G$, $\epsilon_G:As(Conj(G))\to G$ is an group isomorphism.

I expect that $\epsilon_G(e_g)=g$ holds since it follows that:
$$
\epsilon_G(e_g*e_h)=\epsilon_G(e_{h}^{-1}e_g e_h)=\epsilon_G(e_{g*h})=g*h.
$$
In addition, I identify $e_g$ with $g$. I obtain the equality $As(Conj(G))=G$, stronger than the isomorphism. Is it true?

Comment: Never heard about "quandles". Could you give a good reference ?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez: I read the paper. I realized that above $\epsilon$ has opposite domain and codomain and is not an isomorphism. I was also wrong about natural transformation and natural isomorphism! Therefore, I now believe that $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is a counterexample. Since $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is abelian, we have $Conj(\mathbb{Z}_2)\simeq T_2$, which is a trivial quandle. It follows that $As(T_2)\simeq \mathbb{Z}^2$. There is no isomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}_2$ to $\mathbb{Z}^2$ like above $\epsilon$, is there?

Comment: @JeanMarie: A quandle is an algebraic structure, similar to a group, and it was introduced as a knot invariant. I would like to recommend two surveys: Joyce, David. "A classifying invariant of knots, the knot quandle." Journal of Pure and Applied Algebra 23.1 (1982): 37-65. Elhamdadi, Mohamed, and Sam Nelson. Quandles. Vol. 74. American Mathematical Soc., 2015.

Comment: @Apochette Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assertion is not correct and $As(Conj(G))\ncong G$ holds in general since the above $\varepsilon_G$ is not an isomorphism. In fact, there is a counterexample: $G=\mathbb{Z}_2$. For abelian, we have $Conj(\mathbb{Z}_2)\cong T_2$, which means a trivial quandle. It follows that $As(T_2)\cong \mathbb{Z}^2$. However, there is no isomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}^2$ to $\mathbb{Z}_2$.